# Dependency Injection using Scala within AWS Lambda

Tags: scala, aws-lambda

I'm trying to get the resource reused instead of create per invocation.

```
class MessageHandler() {

  var messageProcessor: MessageProcessor = _

  // Constructor something like below to reuse messageProcessor among invocations, but it wont work as it complains dup constructor
  //def this() {
  // this()
  // val injector = Guice.createInjector(some module)
  // messageProcessor = injector.getInstance(..)
  //}

  def handle(sqsEvent: SQSEvent): Unit = {
    messageProcessor.process(sqsEvent)
  }
}
```

However, in Scala, I cannot overload the default constructor (no-args in this case), is there a way to do that?

I tried to create a companion object and moved Guice injection there, but no luck.

The ugly way to make this working is to create a fake arg within constructor:

```
  def this() {
    this(fake arg)
    val injector = Guice.createInjector(some module)
    messageProcessor = injector.getInstance(..)
  }
```

Wondering if there is a better way to do that?